# Chow ring of a $\mu_2$-gerbe

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, intersection-theory, enumerative-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Suppose that $X$ is a stack, and $Y \to X$ is a $\mu_2$-gerbe. Is there any relationship between the integral Chow rings (in the sense of Edidin and Graham) of $X$ and $Y$?

(I assume they become isomorphic upon inverting $2$; the meat here is what happens at the prime $2$...)

Comment: I have only recently come across your question. Do you actually mean a $\mu_2$-torsor ?